# How can I execute a command inside another folder and return to original directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I use this command to `make` inside a folder:

```
cd build/ && make
```

But I want to return to original directory after the command

I tried this:

```
cd build/ && make && cd ..
```

But this doesn't work. How can I do it? Would help in quick testing...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a subshell, like so:

```
$ pwd
/tmp

$ (cd build && make)

$ pwd
/tmp
```

The shell forks before running the commands in brackets, so once it completes it's as if you never left the current directory.

Comment: It is the same reason why running commands in a script doesn't change the working directory.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want [pushd and popd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd).

The `pushd` command will push the current directory onto a stack, saving it and allowing you to change to some other directory. The `popd` command will pop the last saved directory from the stack.

Comment: Probably better for a script rather than CLI

Answer (score 1):

You can use below commands

```
cd build; 
make;
cd -
```

Answer (score 0):

Use popd/pushd:

```
pushd build ; make ; popd
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following command:

```
cd $DIR && make && cd -;
```

to return to the previous directory after running your make, this work even if the path in $DIR is long.

If you want to go for more sophisticate tools like playing with **a stack of accessed directory** you can use:

```
pushd, popd
```

Usage:

```
$ pushd some_directory
It acts as a:
$ cd some_directory
except that some_directory is also added to the stack.
"$ pushd ~/TMP  # we're in ~/
~/TMP ~
$ pushd ~/DATA  # now we're in ~/TMP
~/DATA ~/TMP ~
$ pushd ~  # now we're in ~/DATA
~ ~/DATA ~/TMP ~
$ popd   # now we're in ~/
~/DATA ~/TMP ~
$ popd   # now we're in ~/DATA
~/TMP ~
$ popd   # now we're in ~/TMP
~
$    # now we're in ~/"
```

**another very good approach** is this function that I really likes:

```
"cd_func ()
{   
    local x2 the_new_dir adir index;
    local -i cnt;
    if [[ $1 == ""--"" ]]; then
        dirs -v;
        return 0;
    fi;
    the_new_dir=$1;
    [[ -z $1 ]] && the_new_dir=$HOME;
    if [[ ${the_new_dir:0:1} == '-' ]]; then
        index=${the_new_dir:1};
        [[ -z $index ]] && index=1;
        adir=$(dirs +$index);
        [[ -z $adir ]] && return 1;
        the_new_dir=$adir;
    fi;
    [[ ${the_new_dir:0:1} == '~' ]] && the_new_dir=""${HOME}${the_new_dir:1}"";
    pushd ""${the_new_dir}"" > /dev/null;
    [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return 1;
    the_new_dir=$(pwd);
    popd -n +11 2> /dev/null > /dev/null;
    for ((cnt=1; cnt <= 10; cnt++))
    do  
        x2=$(dirs +${cnt} 2>/dev/null);
        [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && return 0;
        [[ ${x2:0:1} == '~' ]] && x2=""${HOME}${x2:1}"";
        if [[ ""${x2}"" == ""${the_new_dir}"" ]]; then
            popd -n +$cnt 2> /dev/null > /dev/null;
            cnt=cnt-1;
        fi;
    done;
    return 0
}"
```

In your profile/bashrc, **alias cd to this function**:

```
alias cd=cd_func
```

and then you can type:

```
"$ cd --
 0  ~
 1  ~/DATA
 2  ~/TMP"

to see all the directories you've visited. To go ~/TMP, for example, enter:

$ cd -2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.